# How to change width of MuiInputBase-root?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize a text input field. However, I am having trouble adjusting the width of the text field. To be more specific. I want to change the width of class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInputBase formControl MuiInput-formControl", because it is somehow set to 800px and is outside my grid. But I don't know how to access it and override it? See the image below.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  formControlRoot: {
    border: "2px solid lightgreen",
    width:"50%",
    padding: 2,
    marginTop: 10
  },
  inputRoot: {
    border: "2px solid blue",
    width:"50%",
  },
  inputLabelRoot: {
    border: "2px solid pink",
    width:"50%",
  },
  formHelperTextRoot: {
    border: "2px solid red",
    width:"50%",
  },

  underline: {
      color: 'red' ,

      '&::after': {
        border: '2px solid red',
        width:"50%",
      },
       '&::before': {
        border: '2px solid red',
        width:"50%",
      }
    }
});
```

```
<TextField 
        helperText="My Helper Text"
         width="75%"
        classes={{ root: classes.formControlRoot }}
        InputProps={{ classes: { underline: classes.underline }  }}
        InputLabelProps={{ classes: { root: classes.inputLabelRoot } }}
        FormHelperTextProps={{ classes: { root: classes.formHelperTextRoot } }}
      />
```

[image]

Comment: check that class and give the width, if it is already in `!important` then make higher specificity and add `important`, so it will apply and override the `!important`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to set the with you can pass the class to the root `input-base` element.

```
<TextField 
  helperText="My Helper Text"
  width="75%"
  InputProps={{ classes: { underline: classes.underline, root:classes.inputRoot }  }}
  InputLabelProps={{ classes: { root: classes.inputLabelRoot } }}
  FormHelperTextProps={{ classes: { root: classes.formHelperTextRoot } }}
/>
```

ANd here is the `useStyle`:-

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  inputRoot:{
    width:'300px'
  }
}));
```

Provide the required width to the `inputRoot` element.

Working codesanbox link:- https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wpqme

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep other props of input when use in Autocomplete use this

```
renderInput={(params) => (<TextField 
    helperText="My Helper Text"
     width="75%"
    InputProps={{
         ...params.InputProps,
         classes: {
            underline: classes.underline
            root: classes.inputRoot,
         },
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{ classes: { root: classes.inputLabelRoot } }}
    FormHelperTextProps={{ classes: { root: classes.formHelperTextRoot } }}
/>)
```